# Vite. Change build folder from 'dist' to 'docs'. Fix paths from index.html to assets

Tags: config, vite

Default `vite.config.js` file:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

This modified `vite.config.js` file solves the following problems:

1. Output build files to a 'docs' folder (instead of default 'dist'). This makes it easy to publish to Git Pages.
2. Fix the file paths between `index.html` and `assets` folder. The default path is `"/assets/[files]"`. The path required for the files to show on Git Pages is `"./assets/[files]"`

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir: "docs",
  },
  base: "./",
})
```